# How can I include a lightning component in a record detail page in salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I have created a lightning component and am able to add it in desktop view in account record detail page by using lightning record pages but when I switch to SF1 I can not find my lightning component in account record detail page.

Is there a way to make lightning component available in SF1 in record detail pages?

I do not wish to wrap my lightning component in a visual force page. Please suggest some way of achieving it by either using lightning pages or lightning component itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, wondering if you figured this out? We have a custom detail view component with a lot of conditional rendering, but are unable to deploy it in mobile view. It defaults to native detail view with no option to override.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know at present is to create a `Lightning Quick Action` for that Component and add it to your Page Layout, then `Salesforce1` will show it in QuickAction Bar when you're viewing the Detail View of the record.

**Update:**

The other alternative is to use `Lightning Out` for placing the `Lightning Component` in `Visualforce Page`

[Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

Then the `Visualforce Page` can be added to the Page Layout and it will show up in S1 as well within Detail View.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response but I'm searching for a way to somehow embed my lightning component inside the SF1 record detail pages view. Does SF1 support it?

Comment: No, not at present. You could go with a Lightning Out option using Visualforce - [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) and then place the VF page as inline panel on page layout.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In ipad settings ->  selected Salesforce App and “Allow Cross-Website Tracking”
And update apps and pages for mobile and update pagelayout for downloadable app (Lightning on tablet: full-width. Pilot feature. See below
) in Setup - > New Salesforce Mobile App QuickStart.